# UISearchController combined with UIAlertController issue when trying to input text on tvOS

Tags: swift, uitextfield, tvos, uialertcontroller, uisearchcontroller

Issue when combining `UISearchController` with `UIAlertController` that has a `UITextField` on tvOS.

I have a `UIButton` that presents a `UISearchController` with a `UISearchResultsController`.

Somehow the input view (keyboard screen) is not showing on the screen, when hitting the `UITextField` from the `UIAlertController`

Code below, as well with test project link, and video demo of the problem.

ViewController.swift - from here I show the searchController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let searchResultsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SearchResultsViewController")
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        show(searchController, sender: self)
    }

}
```

SearchResultsViewController.swift - When tapping a cell from the `collectionView` I present an `UIAlertController` with a `UITextField`. Tapping on that text field will not show the input view (keyboard screen)

```
class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField { (textfield) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Action here doen't show the keyboard to input text..."
        }

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
            print(ac.textFields?.first?.text)
        }
        ac.addAction(ok)
        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Video link [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8669046/Untitled.mov)

Test project link [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8669046/testtv.zip)

Any ideas, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problems when I worked with the `UISearchController` and `UISearchResultsController`. I solved it by migration to the hybrid application. I implemented a search with the `searchTemplate` and show it when user need to search something. But you can also try easiest way - you can implement `UIAlertController` as a TVML-popup (you can use the item `formTemplate` to do it).